Are projective birational morphisms blowups?
This question seems to claim that a projective birational maps $f: X \to Y$ between varieties $X,Y$ over $\mathbb C$ is a blow-up. What is a reference for that?
According to Wikipedia,

The "Weak factorization theorem", proved by Abramovich, Karu, Matsuki, and Włodarczyk (2002), says that any birational map between two smooth complex projective varieties can be decomposed into finitely many blow-ups or blow-downs of smooth subvarieties.

But what if $X$ and $Y$ are not smooth? The above question is especially motivated by the case that $f$ is the normalization map.

I assume your $f$ is a morphism (not just a map in the sense that is meant in the factorization theorem). If $Y$ is quasi-projective this is Hartshorne Theorem II.7.17.

I believe what that post was referring to the following theorem from Hartshorne’s Algebraic Geometry,

The important thing to note here is that the $\pi$ constructed in the theorem is the blow-up of an ideal sheaf on $X$. The Weak Factorization Theorem is much harder as we require the blow-ups to have smooth centers and it does not hold for singular varieties.
